# What is the UINavigatioBar height in new devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

What is the UINavigatioBar height in following devices ? It increased in proportion of resolution or remain same as before ?

1. iPhone 6
2. iPhone 6s
3. iPhone 6 Plus
4. iPhone 6s Plus
5. iPad pro (12.9")
   Does anyone know ? Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: If your question was successfully answered please accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationBar` height show below:

```
iPhone 6-> 88px
iPhone 6s->88px
iPhone 6 Plus->132px
iPhone 6s Plus->132px
```

Refer this link -> http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2):

You can get the height of the navigation bar by using

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

This'll give you for the different orientations the following point values (portrait/landscape):

- iPhone 6: 44/32
- iPhone 6 Plus: 44/44
- iPhone 6s: 44/32
- iPhone 6s Plus: 44/44
- iPad Pro: 44/44

Check [this guide](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified) for a good overview on points and pixels in iOS.